# How to find the image under a Möbius transformation.

Tags: complex-analysis

Find the image of the set $D_1\cap D_2$, where $$D_1 = \{z : |z| < 1\}$$ and
$$D_2 = \{z : |z + 1/2| > 1/2\}$$ under the transformation
$$f(z) = \frac{z − i}{z + 1}$$

I have done the picture of $D_1\cap D_2$, but I don't know how to do it. If anybody could help me, please. Thanks!

Comment: Can you find the image of $D_1$? And then can you find the image of $D_2$? And then can you intersect the images?

Comment: I know that is the idea, the problem is that I don't know how to find the image of each of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $f^{-1}(z) = \frac{z + i}{1 - z}$.

Let $w \in f(D_1)$. Then $f^{-1}(w) \in D_1$ and by definition we have $|f^{-1}(w)| = \left|\frac{w+i}{1-w}\right| < 1$, that is

$$|w+i| < |w-1|$$

So we can conclude that $f(D_1)$ contains all points $w$ that are closer to $-i$ than they are to $1$, i.e. the "half plane" $\{x+iy \mid y<-x\}$. Now you can use the same method to determine $f(D_2)$.

Then you only need to think about how $f(D_1)$, $f(D_2)$ and $f(D_1 \cap D_2)$ are related.

Comment: I don't understand why by the inequality you can conclude that it is that half plane.

Comment: To convince yourself, draw a coordinate system and mark the two points $-i$ and $1$. Then for some randomly chosen points try to determine whether it is closer to $-i$ than $1$ or not. (And choose maybe blue for those that are, and red for those that are not.)

Comment: @IreneGil: Recall the following useful fact: the set of points in the plane equidistant from two points $p$ and $q$ is a *line*, namely the perpendicular bisector of the line segment between $p$ and $q$ (see the second sentence [here on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection#Line_segment_bisector)). Now it should be intuitively clear that the set of points closer to $p$ than $q$ is the half-plane on one side of that line.

Comment: If I do the computations I get the half plane $y<-x$ (by substituting in the inequality $w=x+iy$ and computing the modules.

Comment: You're right, I forgot the minus sign. It is now corrected!

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that boundaries of $D_1$ and $D_2$ has the common point $-1\in \Bbb{C}$ and $f(-1)=\infty.$ Therefore image of both boundaries under $f$ must be lines and $f(D_1\cap D_2)$ must be the region bounded by those lines. To find those two lines exactly, you can use another two points on boundaries of $D_1$ and $D_2$ respectively.